# why my python calculator doesn't work well?

Tags: python

my calculator doesn't work as excepted
it still ask to input second number although i entered that

```
print("Python Basic Calculator Version 1.12")

print('''
type in the math operation you would like to complete:
+ for addition
- for subtraction
* for multiplication
/ for division
** for power
% for modulo
''')

def main():
    
    def asd():
    
        try:

            global x

            x = int(input("enter first number: "))

        except ValueError:

            print("you don't enter correct")

            asd()
    asd()        

    def jkl():

        ops = ["+","-","*","/","**","%"]

        o = input("type the opreation: ")

        if o in ops:

            def qwe():
    
                try:

                    global y

                    y = int(input("enter second number: "))

                except ValueError:

                    print("you don't enter correct")

                qwe()

            qwe()        

            if o == "+": 

                z = x + y

                print(z)

            if o == "-":  

                z = x - y

                print(z)

            if o == "*":

                z = x * y

                print(z)

            if o == "/":

                z = x / y

                print(z)

            if o == "**":

                z = x ** y

                print(z)

            if o == "%":

                z = x % y

                print(z)

        else:

            print("you don't enter correct")

            jkl() 

    jkl()

main()
```

I join them in one function

Comment: Please make your code readable: don't put newlines between each line, and please, please use *meaningful* names for variables and functions. I strongly recommend that you read the [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) style guide for Python, which is very well respected by Python programmers.

Answer (score 1):

```
def qwe():
    try:
        global y
        y = int(input("enter second number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("you don't enter correct")
    qwe()
```

The last line of this function has wrong indentation.  It should be indented underneath the `except` block, so that it is *only* called when there is an exception.

Because it is not indented, it is *always* called, so that function calls itself endlessly.

Comment: Worth noting that doing a loop by defining a local recursive function and having it set a global is bad for multiple reasons.  Using a `while` loop is much simpler and therefore less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use recursion for your user prompts.  In theory, your user could reach a RecursionError if they keep entering invalid values.  You should instead use a `try/except` block inside of a `while` loop to handle if the user input can't be converted to an int or float.
You would also find your code easier to debug with meaningful function and variable names as Theirry Lathuille mentions in his comment.

Here is a slightly more elaborate solution, but it breaks everything into functions, including getting user input, and uses a dictionary to get the supported operations instead of an if/elif block.

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y


def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y


def division(x, y):
    return x / y


def exponent(x, y):
    return x ** y


def modulo(x, y):
    return x % y


def get_operand(label):
    while True:
        try:
            value = input(f"Enter {label} number: ")
            if value.lower() in ['help', '?']:
                help()
                continue
            return float(value)
        except ValueError:
            print("\nPlease enter a valid number!")

OPS = {
    "+": add,
    "-": subtract,
    "*": multiply,
    "/": division,
    "**": exponent,
    "%": modulo 
}


def get_operator():
    while True:
        operator = input("Enter the operator: ")
        if operator in OPS:
            return operator
        elif operator.lower() in ['help', '?']:
                help()
                continue
        print(f"{operator} is not a supported operation.  Please choose from {list(OPS.keys())}")


def help():
    print(''' type in the math operation you would like to complete:
    + for addition
    - for subtraction
    * for multiplication
    / for division
    ** for power
    % for modulo 
    ''')


def main():
    print("Python Basic Calculator Version 1.12")
    help()

    while True:
        a = get_operand("first")
        op = get_operator()
        b = get_operand("second")

        result = OPS[op](a, b)
        # Drop non-signicant decimals.

        if result % 1 == 0.0:
            result = int(result)
        print(result)

        again = input("Would you like to make another calculation (Y/N)? ")
        if again.strip().lower()[0] != 'y':
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```